# plesk panel using host user in Connection String in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, plesk

I have developed a web apllication in asp.net with its connection String in web.config file and working very well in localhost. But when i deployed to hosting server using windows shared hosting it fives the error

Logic failed for user anama76

where anama76 is my domain user.My database userName is anama_Muneeb. I am finding it difficult to know that why connection string is using the domain user to connect to Db.

I have used connection in web.config to make sql server authentication

What is the solution

Comment: Could you please share your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string must match the user name:

```
<add 
name="ConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=your_database_server;Initial Catalog=your_database_name;User Id=anama_Muneeb;Password='your_password';" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```